# Sequence Diagram for Registration and Reporting

Tags: uml, sequence, diagram

I am doing sequence diagrams, but I have some issues in the design of these diagrams. So I was doing the diagram for Account Creation as follows:

[image]

So, first the user goes to the registration page and then enters his information. I also wanted to show what would happen if the information entered by the user in the registration page are incorrect: I added the verify input arrow from the registration page to the database.

1. I am not sure who should verify that the input is correct, is it correct to say it's the database that checks if the entered data are valid?
2. Moreover, is it correct to add the dashed arrow from the database to the registration page or should I go directly to the if condition?
3. What would you advice me to change?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> 1) ..who should verify..input...database..?

You can delegate the responsibility for data validation to whichever actor with whatever name. Database is good candidate, and many `SQL` databases have some kind of [integrity constraint](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-integrity-constraints.htm) checking mechanism built-in

- If configured, such database will validate data and reject them at the moment of `insert/update` attempt. So in your case if a `SQL` database would handle it the way they usually do, the `VerificationResult` would be returned from `AddNewUser()` message, not sooner
- However, for real-life application the good candidates according to [Open Web Application Security Project (OWASP) → Data Validation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Data_Validation) would be:

  > ..**Integrity checks** must be included **wherever data passes from a trusted to a less trusted boundary**, such as from the application to the user's browser in a hidden field, or to a third party payment gateway, such as a transaction ID used internally upon return..
  >
  > ..**Validation** must be performed **on every [tier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture)**..

> 2) ..dashed arrow from the database to the registration page..directly to the if..?

**I would** extend the [execution (activation)](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html#execution) down as shown below, but it **does not mean** that your way is not correct

[image]

See also: [uml-diagrams.org: UML Sequence Diagrams Examples](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-examples.html#facebook-authentication)

> 3) ..advice..to change?

I would review the use of [synchronous/asynchronous](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html#synchronous-call) messages. It seems that you use one type of arrow for everything

Comment: I don't see a difference between my diagram and what you posted ?

Comment: @simon just the green bar is different. In my version it's one uninterrupted block, where the further negotiation details are meant like `overlapping execution` or nested function calls. But it's just the way I would draw it, based on the examples from `uml-diagrams.org`. I did not check what [www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta2](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta2/) says about the `notation`, neither some other sources, I'm sorry for that and I'm not saying that your version is incorrect. My-inside-head syntax validator is broken, I don't see a problem here but that means nothing

Comment: Ah yes I didn't see that, yeah I tought about the same.
Btw our professor never taught us about synchornous and aynchronous messages before.
What do you think about the report management sequence diagram I have just added?

Comment: @simon in the report diagram I would use filled fat arrow heads (synchronous call) and no interruption in the `Reports Page` lifeline (assuming that there will be rotating hour glass cursor shown on the screen between the moment when user clicks the `RequestReport` button and the moment when `Confirmed` message box appears)

Comment: In which arrow?
But what do you think about the confirmation arrow from the database? Should it be there? I find it somehow useless.
The way I want it to be is that when I click on the generateReport button, it will get data from DB and either display the report or download it.

Comment: @simon in the diagram you use [asynchronous call](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html#asynchronous-call) arrow style and [reply message](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html#reply) arrow style. I would change the `asynchronous` to `synchronous` (no `a`). It seems that you want to draw another alternate messages send by the user to the "printer actor" or to a "screen controller actor" after the database confirmed that the report is ready to be used. [Relax, draw, paper & pencil is best for fast prototyping](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/sequenceDiagram.htm)

Comment: You told me " the VerificationResult would be returned from AddNewUser() message, not sooner" why is that?
First, I check if the input is valid, then if it is valid, the user is added to the database. The verification result only means that a response of wheiter the input is valid or not, it is not a message displayed or anything. Isn't a right way to do it?

Comment: @simon it depends on you database engine. But typical `SQL` engines would validate the data with [BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER or AFTER INSERT TRIGGER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger) semantics. There's no standard `SQL` way to just have a look at a `what-if` scenario. You can implement it and even the database may support it, but typical `SQL` developers/engines don't